# Assigning values to pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, structure, kernighan-and-ritchie

In Dennis Ritchie I found this,

```
struct rect r , *rp = r;
```

then these four expressions are equivalent :

1. `r.pt1.x`
2. `rp->pt1.x`
3. `(r.pt1).x`
4. `(rp->pt1).x`

because operators associate left to right.
Shouldn't it be struct rect *rp = &r?

Comment: I m confused because i thought ritchie cant make a mistake :P

Comment: Perhaps Ritchie can't make a mistake, but the type setters can, especially when the text is not in a human language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely -- the address operator is required, [otherwise you get a compile-time error](http://ideone.com/CG3aEx):

```
incompatible types when initializing type ‘struct rect *’ using type ‘struct rect’
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it definitely should, as `rp` is a pointer-to-`struct rect`, whereas `r` is of type `struct rect`. Maybe a typo in the book?

Answer (score 0):

It was a typo in the book, and it's been corrected in later editions.

The book in question is ["The C Programming Language", 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628), by Kernighan and Ritchie, commonly referred to as "K&R2". It's not generally referred to as "Ritchie", since he was just one of the two authors. (Some of you might be interested in knowing that it's now available as a Kindle e-book.)

The [errata list](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/cbook/2ediffs.html) for the book says:

> A later printing in October, 1989, made minor changes on page
>   131(§6.2) to add `&` to the last example ( `struct rect r, *rp = &r;`), on
>   page 208(§A.17) to change "equal" to "unequal" in the description
>   of logical OR, and on page 254(§B.8) to clarify that for automatics
>   variables, only those declared `volatile` are restored to their latest
>   values after a `setjmp` / `longjmp` sequence.

(And yes, the phrase "automatics variables" should be "automatic variables".)